# python bindings for selenium returns in exception when initiating a Firefox webdriver object

Tags: python, selenium

When on windows I want to give a try with the webdriver extension for selenium, I get an error. I installed the python bindings like on the installation page. And then I try to to just the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Firefox (15.0) is opened and after that an exception occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.32.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.32.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.32.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 114, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.32.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.32.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 152, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ''
```

I tried the same without webdriver, with the 1.0 api and then I can open Firefox and go to a specific page, but with the webdriver case I do not have any luck. Has anyone a clue what I do wrong ? 
My OS is Windos 7, 64 bit version.
I also tried the same with the latest python bindings from version control, but that has the same error.

Comment: have you started the java selenium server?

Comment: yes, I did, with the command java -jar seleniumserver.jar

Comment: to use webdriver API from Python, you don't need to start the java server.

Comment: With latest versions it seems to work. Do not know what I did wrong at that time.